# Failed to connect to http://localhost:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, docker-compose, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins using docker container and accessing it on localhost:8080 using following command:

```sh
sudo docker run --name uditgauravtest11 -p 8085:8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock uditgaurav/test:1
```

Now I've accessed the Jenkins web UI at http://localhost:8080

I'm setting up a pipeline using this git repo https://github.com/uditgaurav/jenkins-template

here the pipeline uses Kubernetes YAML to run as part of the job for which I configured a separate GKE cluster and connected it to the Jenkins using `Manage Jenkins > Manage Node and Cloud > Configure Jenkins`

Now when I trigger the Jenkins Job It starts one slave pod on the GKE cluster which have two containers one `jnlp` container running with `jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4` image and another one which I mention in the Git repo pod-delete.yml (https://github.com/uditgaurav/jenkins-template)

But the `jnlp` container immediately goes into a failed state after coming to a running state with the following error and the pod gets terminated and a new pod comes up.

command:

```
# "docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2" is the slave pod created on the cluster
kubectl logs -f docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2  -c jnlp
```

error:

```
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 4.3
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using /home/jenkins/agent/remoting as a remoting work directory
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/jenkins/agent/remoting
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://localhost:8080/]
Jan 10, 2021 2:40:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Failed to connect to http://localhost:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to http://localhost:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:217)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:693)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:214)
    ... 2 more
```

The Console Output from Jenkins jobs shows that it continuously creates and deletes the same pod due to this error.

Console Output:

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/uditgaurav/jenkins-template
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] readTrusted
Obtained pod-delete.yaml from git https://github.com/uditgaurav/jenkins-template
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: kubernetes default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8 to gke-cluster-1-default-pool-57712ddb-q2j7
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Pulling] Pulling image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Created] Created container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Started] Started container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-xbng8][Started] Started container jnlp
Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘docker_test_68-xwmvf’
Created Pod: kubernetes default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm to gke-cluster-1-default-pool-57712ddb-q2j7
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Pulling] Pulling image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Created] Created container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Started] Started container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-26sxm][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: kubernetes default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x to gke-cluster-1-default-pool-57712ddb-q2j7
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Pulling] Pulling image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Created] Created container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Started] Started container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-dgx3x][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: kubernetes default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Scheduled] Successfully assigned default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2 to gke-cluster-1-default-pool-57712ddb-9j14
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Pulling] Pulling image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "litmuschaos/chaos-ci-lib:v0.3.0"
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Created] Created container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Started] Started container pod-delete
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][default/docker-test-68-xwmvf-b6w6f-fmpd2][Started] Started container jnlp
```

I the gone through some similar issues and tried to resolve them for which I provided different values in `Dashboard > Configure Global Security`  in TCP port for inbound agents. I kept it fixed with 50000 but it is still occurring. Now I changed it to Random but it doesn't resolve the issue.

[image]

Any help on this?
Please let me know If I need to share some more information.

Comment: This is not gonna work. Your jenkins is running locally and the slaves in the GKE environment. The master spawn a slave in the cloud, which tries again to get connection to the master, which is running on localhost. That's why it's failing immediately. in best case you let jenkins and slaves run in the same cluster and endpoint shouldn't be localhost. It should also be available for the slaves.

Answer (score 2):

ERROR: SEVERE: Failed to connect to http://localhost:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: Connection refused (Connection refused)

First, ensure your GKE cluster can connected to your Jenkins master host's 50000 TCP port.(telnet 12.12.12.12 50000)

Your agent Failed to connect to the Jenkins master, if they not on same host, you need to setting up the "Jenkins URL" (Manage Jenkins > Manage Node and Cloud > Configure Jenkins -> Kubernetes) like "http://12.12.12.12:8080"